# Understanding reductions and notation

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, reductions, notation

I am currently working through Sipser's Introduction to the Theory of Computation. In chapter 5, he defines that a Language $A$ is mapping reducible to language $B$, written $A\leq_m B$ if there is a computable function $f:\Sigma^*\rightarrow\Sigma^*$ where for every $w$, $w\in A \iff f(w)\in B$, where $f$ is called the reduction from $A$ to $B$ (Definition 5.20 in the 3rd edition). My understanding of this definition is that $B$ is the "simpler" language we map to, in order to understand $A$.

The notation $\leq_m$ in a way makes some sense because in my mind, it's similar to series: If $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ diverges, and if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, compared to if $A\leq_m B$ and $A$ is undecidable, then $B$ is undecidable, and likewise if $B$ is decidable then $A$ is decidable.

With a word like "reduction" it seems that if $A$ reduces to $B$, then $A$ was "harder" than $B$ and $B$ should be "simpler" as you reduced to it. On the contrary, the notation $A \leq_m B$ also seems to imply that $A$ is "simpler" than $B$.  This understanding seems to be exactly opposite of all the definitions, as $A$ is the one being reduced to $B$ and not the other way around. What is the problem with my understanding? Am I simply reading too much into notation and confusing myself?

Comment: "My understanding of this definition is that $B$ is the "simpler" language we map to, in order to understand $A$." - No. For example, $A$ can be an empty language $\emptyset$ (arguably the simplest), which reduces to almost every language. In very simplified terms, the definition says: "if you can compute $B$, then you can compute $A$". It potentially allows an option "you can compute $A$ but can't compute $B$", so $A$ is potentially simpler. "On the contrary, the notation $A\le_m B$  also seems to imply that $A$ is "simpler" than $B$" - Yes.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83903/the-directionality-of-reductions?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The 'directionality' of reductions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83903/the-directionality-of-reductions)

Answer (score 0):

You rightly infer that the term *reduction* was chosen because it makes the problem easier; but not the problem you're thinking of.

We're trying to determine the complexity of deciding the language A. There are two problems here:

1. the problem of deciding the language A
2. the problem of deciding the complexity of deciding the language A

Reduction doesn't make problem 1 any easier; its purpose is to make problem 2 easier, by translating problem 1 into a different problem for which we have already solved problem 2.

So we have a language B, and

3. the problem of deciding the language B
4. the problem of deciding the complexity of deciding the language B

for which 4 is already solved, and the reduction makes 2 easier by making it possible to apply 4.

The reduction doesn't make 1 any easier, nor does it imply 3 is easier than 1.  It implies the opposite:

- The reduction translates all As into a subset of Bs, such that deciding that subset is just as easy as deciding A.
- We then say:

  - we know how hard it is (4) to decide *all* Bs (3)
  - so deciding that subset can't be any harder,
  - so deciding A (1) can't be any harder than deciding B (3)
- but it may be easier:

  - there may be a smarter way to decide that subset of B than the best way we have for deciding all of B.